# Libgdx. No music on Android emulator and device. Desktop app is okay

Tags: android, libgdx

My code is as follows:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
 ...
public static Sound music;
String musicFile;
if (ANDROID) musicFile="music.mp3";
else musicFile="assets/music.mp3";
music=Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal(musicFile));
music.play();
music.loop();
```

It plays on Desktop app.
But what's wrong on Emulator and smartphone?
ANDROID=true for Android and false for desktop app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a slight missunderstanding how assets are managed by libgdx. Please refer to http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling and the rest of the wiki. There's no need to special case for a platform.

You should also always post stack traces for others to help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I could not understand... What should I do? I use the same algorithm  for all other files. And it works. There is no exception that file not found. All works, but with no music. Thanks

Comment: Android version does not work if  file names are such as "assets/music.mp3". Files should be such as "music.mp3". And the main question again is why the music does not play.